# Home prestashop keep loading without result?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I move my site to another server , and I have probleme when I open It is keep loading without any result, but when I disable all modules Is work .

Comment: I'm afraid you need to enable all modules, and then disable modules one by one until you find which is causing the problem.

Comment: Enable all modules that you want first; enable debug mode by editing `config/defines.inc.php` file. set `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `true`. Then after load your site and post all errors/warnings you see.